# Why non-type template parameters must have only public members in c++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

See code below

```
#include <algorithm>

template<std::size_t N>
struct DoubleString
{
    constexpr DoubleString(char const(&pp)[N])
    {
        std::copy(std::cbegin(pp), std::cend(pp), std::begin(p));
        std::copy(std::cbegin(pp), std::cend(pp), std::begin(p) + N - 1);
    }
    
    constexpr auto data() const { return p; }

//private: //ERROR IF UNCOMMENTED

    char p[N + N - 1]{};
};

template<DoubleString A>
constexpr auto operator""_x2()
{
    return A.data();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto str = "Hello"_x2;
    std::cout << str;
}
```

on cppreference we can read following terms:

> A non-type template parameter must have a structural type, which is
> one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers
> are ignored):
> ....
> ....
> **a literal class type with the following properties:**
> all base classes and **non-static data members are public**
> and non-mutable and the types of all base classes and non-static data
> members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array
> thereof.

I don't understand why private members not allowed?